# Can not update gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

So in this photo I have a gridview,

[image]

Column 1 is DropDownList, Column 2 is TextBox and Column 3 is Read Only. for Column 1 as a TextBox, when I clicked Edit, changed the value of TextBox and then I clicked Update, the Value of Column 1 chenged. Then I replaced TextBox from column 1 to a DropDownList. I converted Column1 into a TemplateField, Edited template field of column 1 and changed it as a DropDownList. Now When I try to Edit a Row, I choose another value from DropDownList and it doesn't change.
NOTE: I haven't don this programmatically. .aspx.cs file is empty. I have done this via GridView Tasks.

Comment: You are describing your problem (which still is mildly unclear), but you also need to _ask a question_. The implied "why doesn't this work" is not a question.

Comment: Automatic gridview edits only work with Boundfields. If your gridview needs to be more complicated than that, you'll have to handle the updates programmatically in your code behind. Here's a page with [an example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs).

Comment: Well, it used to work one day ago. Now I do now why.

Comment: @gunr2171 Why isn't the implied question, "why doesn't this work," a question?

Comment: @user1477388 It's implied, not explicit, and too broad. We haven't seen any code, so the OP is not providing enough information (and I can't see the screenshot, blocked on my internet).

Comment: @gunr2171 because your internet blocked the screenshot doesn't mean it's not a implied question. anyway I found the solution and I answered here, and I'm sure you will not understand because it has screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to fix the problem.

On EditTemplateField, on DropDownList I clicked Edit Data Bindings

[image]

After that on Selected Value I bounded it to the column I want.

[image]